# Can't access data from api in webview javafx

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, javafx-8

Can't load data from api only html designing is presents.

I am use hibernate-spring mongodb in back-end for data.in front-end angular2. when i am access url from javafx webview it does't display data.

> javafx code:

```
final WebView browser = new WebView();
            final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
            webEngine.load("http://192.168.2.6:4200/");
            webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            browser.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
                    System.out.println(browser.getEngine().getLoadWorker().exceptionProperty());
                }
            });
            TrustManager trm = new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {

                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            };

            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, new TrustManager[] { trm }, null);
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
```

> hibernate-spring api:

```
@CrossOrigin
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getById", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public <T> T getById(@RequestParam(ERPUtils.ID_PARAM_FOR_API) String id,
            @RequestParam(ERPUtils.ENTITY_NAME_PARAM_FOR_API) String entityName) {

        T t = null;

        /* It returns rough object of passed id. */
        if (entityName.equalsIgnoreCase(ERPUtils.TABLE_NAME_FOR_ROUGH)) {
            Rough rough = erpService.getById(id, new Rough());
            t = (T) rough;
        }

        if (entityName.equalsIgnoreCase(ERPUtils.TABLE_NAME_FOR_LOT)) {
            t = (T) erpService.getById(id, new Lot());
        }

        if (entityName.equalsIgnoreCase(ERPUtils.TABLE_NAME_FOR_CUT)) {
            Cut cut = erpService.getById(id, new Cut());
            t = (T) cut;
        }

        if (entityName.equalsIgnoreCase(ERPUtils.TABLE_NAME_FOR_PIECE)) {
            Piece piece = erpService.getById(id, new Piece());
            t = (T) piece;
        }

        if (entityName.equalsIgnoreCase(ERPUtils.TABLE_NAME_FOR_TAG)) {
            Tag tag = erpService.getById(id, new Tag());
            t = (T) tag;
        }

        if (entityName.equalsIgnoreCase(ERPUtils.TABLE_NAME_FOR_PLAN)) {
            Plan plan = erpService.getById(id, new Plan());
            t = (T) plan;
        }

        if (entityName.equalsIgnoreCase(ERPUtils.TABLE_NAME_FOR_SUBPLAN)) {
            SubPlan subPlan = erpService.getById(id, new SubPlan());
            t = (T) subPlan;
        }

        if (entityName.equalsIgnoreCase(ERPUtils.TABLE_NAME_FOR_USER)) {
            User user = erpService.getById(id, new User());
            user.setPassword(null);
            user.setEncryptedToken(null);
            t = (T) user;

        }

        if (entityName.equalsIgnoreCase(ERPUtils.TABLE_NAME_FOR_WEIGHT_UNIT)) {
            WeightUnit weightUnit = erpService.getById(id, new WeightUnit());
            t = (T) weightUnit;
        }

        if (entityName.equalsIgnoreCase(ERPUtils.TABLE_NAME_FOR_PRICE_UNIT)) {
            PriceUnit priceUnit = erpService.getById(id, new PriceUnit());
            t = (T) priceUnit;
        }

        return (T) (t == null ? ERPUtils.NO_RECORD_FOUND : t);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly got the answer.

just add following line in javafx.

```
System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
```